# Restrict SSH key to only execute rsync

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-keys

I am working on a backup strategy for my servers with rsync. I followed [this](https://calomel.org/rsync_tips.html) tutorial and to restrict the use of the SSH key, I make of this `validate-rsync.sh` script that I can also run without problems:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in 
*\&*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\(*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\{*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\;*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\<*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\>*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\`*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
*\|*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
rsync\ --server*) 
$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND 
;; 
*) 
echo "Rejected" 
;; 
esac
```

The beginning of the `authorized_keys` file looks like this:

```
command="/home/$USERNAME/validate-rsync.sh" ssh-rsa....
```

As far as I understand, I should not be able to remotely connect via SSH (from the server where the backup lies) and then e.g. execute `mkdir xx`. But somehow, I can still do it. What could be the problem?

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Your authorized key format looks right, so I'd like further at your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I set the command in front of the wrong SSH key... I'm sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 1):

You can force use of rsync by editing the public key in the `authorized_keys` file on the server, like this:

```
command="/usr/bin/rsync -wo /path/to/data",no-port-forwarding ssh-rsa ....
```